# Get changes on a particular file since a commit - GIT

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I am using the following to get the list of all files changed since a commit

> git diff --stat [SHA1]

But, after the list is displayed, i wanted to view the changes is a particular file since the same SHA1. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the changes from that commit until the most recent commit, use the following:

```
git diff <SHA1> HEAD <path/to/file>
```

Naturally, in place of `HEAD` you can use any other expression which resolves to a commit hash (a specific SHA1, `HEAD^`, `master`, etc).

To include changes in your working directory, use

```
git diff <SHA1> <path/to/file>
```

That includes the entire history since that commit plus any uncommitted changes you have.